# Read and merge large tables on computer cluster

Tags: r, merge, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, lapply

I need to merge different large tables (up to 10Gb each) into a single one. To do so I am using a computer cluster with 50+ cores and 10+Gb Ram that runs on Linux.

I always end up with an error message like: "Cannot allocate vector of size X Mb". 
Given that commands like `memory.limit(size=X)` are Windows-specific and not accepted, I cannot find a way around to merge my large tables.

Any suggestion welcome!

This is the code I use:

```
library(parallel)

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt$")
gc()
```

Here the error occurs:

```
myfiles = parLapply(cl,temp, function(x) read.csv(x,
                                        header=TRUE, 
                                        sep=";",
                                        stringsAsFactors=F,
                                        encoding = "UTF-8",
                                        na.strings = c("NA","99","")))



myfiles.final = do.call(rbind, myfiles)
```

Comment: Do you need to work with the data as an R dataframe? Were you to have a dataframe as large as the one you want to make, can you load it? My suggestion would be to use a library like Dask (python) that can handle working with larger data without loading it all into memory if you need to manipulate it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
The issue is really the loading of the tables. I am not bound to merge them as R df, so I will proceed to try out your Python solution. The other alternatives was to use BigQuery and merge them using SQL. I keep you posted.

Comment: what is the RAM on your cluster compute nodes? if you are having issues with dask I can post an example.  Another option, if you are simply concatenating row-wise which I think is happening with rbind, is to use linux "cat" command.  Or if you need more filtering control, you could design a solution where you read each file one by one and write out to a big file.

Comment: It is up to 25. I got a bit lost on dask, tbh - an example might really help me out!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah I feel like you definitely need a low ram approach.  I'll post some of the things I do- (which may not be the "best" ways to do it), but I have this same issue when working on my cluster from time to time.  To help me with an example- does each table have the same order of columns/number of columns? Does each table have a header? Do we need to drop duplicate rows or anything like that?

Comment: Same number of columns in each table (theoretically). 
Might need to drop duplicated rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use merge, for example:

```
`
mergedTable <- merge(table1, table2, by = "dbSNP_RSID")
If your samples have overlapping column names, then you'll find that the mergedTable has (for example) columns called Sample1.x and Sample1.y. This can be fixed by renaming the columns before or after the merge.

Reproducible example:

x <- data.frame(dbSNP_RSID = paste0("rs", sample(1e6, 1e5)),
  matrix(paste0(sample(c("A", "C", "T", "G"), 1e7, replace = TRUE),
    sample(c("A", "C", "T", "G"), 1e7, replace = TRUE)), ncol = 100))
y <- data.frame(dbSNP_RSID = paste0("rs", sample(1e6, 1e5)),
  matrix(paste0(sample(c("A", "C", "T", "G"), 1e7, replace = TRUE),
    sample(c("A", "C", "T", "G"), 1e7, replace = TRUE)), ncol = 100))
colnames(x)[2:101] <- paste0("Sample", 1:100)
colnames(y)[2:101] <- paste0("Sample", 101:200)
mergedDf <- merge(x, y, by = "dbSNP_RSID")
```

`

Comment: Thanks for the effort. The problem in not in the code, but in the underpinning loading issue. These are large tables of up to15m lines each.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this is with python and dask.  The dask dataframe is stored mostly on disk rather than in ram- allowing you to work with larger than ram data- and can help you do computations with clever parallelization.  A nice tutorial of ways to work on big data can be found in this [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/yuliagm/how-to-work-with-big-datasets-on-16g-ram-dask) post which might also be helpful for you. I also suggest checking out the docs on dask performance [here](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-performance.html).  To be clear, if your data can fit in RAM using regular R dataframe or pandas dataframe will be faster.

Here's a dask solution which will assume you have named columns in the tables to align the concat operation.  Please add to your question if you have any other special requirements about the data we need to consider.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import glob

tmp = glob.glob("*.txt")

dfs= []
for f in tmp:
    # read the large tables
    ddf = dd.read_table(f)
    # make a list of all the dfs
    dfs.append(ddf)

#row-wise concat of the data
dd_all = dd.concat(dfs)
#repartition the df to 1 partition for saving
dd_all = dd_all.repartition(npartitions=1)

# save the data 
# provide list of one name if you don't want the partition number appended on
dd_all.to_csv(['all_big_files.tsv'], sep = '\t')
```

if you just wanted to cat all the tables together you can do something like this in straight python.  (you could also use linux cat/paste).

```
with open('all_big_files.tsv', 'w') as O:
    file_number = 0
    for f in tmp:
        with open(f, 'rU') as F:
            if file_number == 0:
                for line in F:
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    O.write(line + '\n')
            else:
                # skip the header line
                l = F.readline()
                for line in F:
                    line = line.rstrip()
                    O.write(line + '\n')
            file_number +=1
```

Comment: I am a little stuck. I produced a toy example with two data sets.
using `dd_all.to_csv('*.csv')` (following: `http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.to_csv`) I am able to print the two partitions (the files I started with), but not a new concatenated file. Any ideas why?

Comment: Ahh I see, good point, I assumed it would let you save it like normal pandas.  Anyway, the problem is the partitions (it's creating one big df with two partitions for manipulating the data) , so what you need to do is "repartition" the concatenated dd_all dataframe before saving, I'll edit the answer above to include this step, let me know if it works

Comment: I think I fixed the issues, let me know if these edits do what you want.

Comment: Ok, python is running since Friday. No signs of completion whatsoever. Clues?

Comment: interesting, when I do this to make a 10g file it seems to work ok.  are you sure its actually running anything? you should top/htop and look at memory consumption on the node.

Comment: If all you really need is the data put together and saved- I'll just add in a straight python approach- but you won't be able to manipulate the data like in dask.